# Using a intersects spatial query as default value in PostGIS table

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

I have two PostgreSQL tables :

table_a (polygon) with field_1
table_b (polygon) with field_2

For field 2, I would like to get the corresponding value in field_2 of the polygons of table 2 inside or touching polygons of table_a

So far I was using a default expression in QGIS :

field_2 = aggregate
('table_a','concatenate',"field_a",intersects ($geometry,geometry(@parent)),',',"field_a")

but I would like to create the same result using the default value inside PostgreSQL directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on *PostgreSQL* > 12.0 you could elegantly use [*Generated Columns*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html):

- create a function to retrieve `<field_1>` values (as array) from `<table_a>` found for all `<geom>` that intersect a `reference_geom`:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION concat_field_values(
    reference_geom GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326)
  ) RETURNS TEXT[] AS
    $$  
    SELECT
      ARRAY_AGG(t.<field_1>::TEXT)
    FROM
      <table_a> AS t
    WHERE
      ST_Intersects(t.<geom>, reference_geom)
    ;
    $$
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE STRICT
    PARALLEL SAFE
  ;
  ```
- add the column definition to `<table_b>` (drop the column before if necessary):

  ```
  ALTER TABLE
    <table_b>
  ADD COLUMN
    <field_2> TEXT[]
      GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( concat_field_values(<geom>) ) STORED
  ;
  ```

---

Traditionally you'd implement a *Trigger*:

- create the trigger function:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION concat_field_values()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
    $$
    BEGIN
      SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(t.<field_1>::TEXT)
      FROM
        <table_a> AS t
      WHERE
        ST_Intersects(t.<geom>, reference_geom)
      INTO
        NEW.<field_2>
      ;

      RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  ;
  ```
- add the *Trigger* to the table:

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER concat_field_values__trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON TABLE <table_b>
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE concat_field_values()
  ;
  ```

---

*Make sure you replace all identifiers wrapped in `<>` with their correct names!*

Both solutions work for `INSERT` operations, and the *Generated Column* approach additionally recalculates the `<field_2>` values when the respective row gets modified.

Neither solution can handle cases where the geometries of other rows change, with side effects on present rows. This would require a more sophisticated *Trigger* setup.

Comment: First solution works but Qgis does not recognize the column format so it's impossible to make any manual changes to these values afterwards wich is not ideal. I tried the second one but when I want to create a new entity I got an error saying that reference_geom does not exist. Also I had to remove the TABLE after ON because of a syntax error according to pgadmin. If I want to be able to edit the values manually afterwards, is it better to use a trigger than generated columns?

Comment: is there a way to use generated columns but to get the same result in a varchar column instead of an array?